# Accessing layout from a different activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm still new in java and android studio. I want to know if there is a way to access a layout in another activity.

What I want is to be able to change the background image of my main activity through a different activity. So my main activity has a button that will direct them to a new activity, and that new activity has some buttons that will customize the background image of the main activity. (basically press a button and the background will change).

In my main.xml I got my constraint layout. How do I access that constraint layout in a different java class?

Comment: I too have researched on this thing a lot with no result. The conclusion I came upon was that a class can access only those widgets that are present in the layout which it inflates.

Comment: If your first activity is still alive, you can send a message from the second activity to the first activity via an interface or an event bus or even live data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do that.
What you need is to pass some data to an activity you want to customize from your costomization activity with intent.
The other way - you can use fragments, for example DialogFragment which is just attached to your mainactivity, so you can change it

Comment: thank you! I guess im using dialogfragment then :)

Comment: i just tried it and it worked T_T tysm, u saved my project!!

Answer (score 0):

@cupcake, You can access the object but you have to create the object name as static.
and call from NewActivity
But your view might be null if you dont call findViewbyId!
Here and example :
**MainAcitvity**

```
static TextView mTextViewTv;
static ConstraintLayout mLayoutCl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextViewTv = findViewById(R.id.helloWorldTv);
    mLayoutCl =findViewById(R.id.mLayout);
    mTextViewTv.setOnClickListener(v -> startNewActivity());
}


private void startNewActivity() {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class));
}
```

**NewActivity**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

  //you can call in on click, **Becareful with NUll expection**
//this is just example
  MainActivity.mLayoutCl.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
}
```

**This type of method NOT RECOMMEND**

Comment: yeah i could access it but it still doesn't change anybackground, i guess its to no avail T_T thank you tho

Comment: ohhhh but mine can changed ,

Comment: @cupcake It didn't change any background because when you return to the previous activity, onCreate() method of that activity will be called, and everything will be turned to the initial position.